# Assign value to multiple variables in subquery

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

How to fetch the values using this query:

```
declare 
status varchar2(4);
Num number:=0;
begin
select (SELECT  MAX(a),b from table Where (id=2) group by b) into Num from dual;
end
```

I've to assign both the column values into declared variables. Written query in this way to avoid no data found exception.

**NOTE**:-Consider this query will return 1-1 value for both the columns.....So please ignore **Too many rows exception**...

Comment: if you query returns more than one record you need use collections, see example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840685/modifying-plsql-function-to-return-multiple-rows-from-same-column/33842205#33842205

Comment: Why would you NOT want to get the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception if there is, in fact, no data to be fetched?

Comment: In general, if you find yourself writing an obtuse sql statement (such as the above) just to avoid having to handle an error, then you're probably making a rod for your own back. People (including yourself!) trying to maintain such code will wonder what you were thinking when you wrote it.

Comment: if you expect more than one row, you will need a collection. If you need to store more than one value, you need another variable.

Comment: Also, what will you be doing with the results of your query once you've obtained them?

Comment: If this query returns no result then we've to perform some other insertions. So my seniors are not accepting to set some flag for that in small exception block..
That's why I've written this.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return the error message: Too many values. The inline select can only return 1 value, not 2.
To fix this one could write:

```
declare
   v_max number;
   v_b   table.b%type;
begin
   select max(a)
         ,b
     into v_max
         ,v_b
     from table
    where id = 2
    group by b;
   -- do something with the selected values

exception
   when no_data_found then
   -- do something when no record with ID=2 is available.

end;
```

But the whole thing is a bit puzzling since the select is on ID=2 which would suggest that is a primary key column and will only return 1 row at most.

Comment: Rene:Thanks for the answer.. But, we will add few more conditions in where clause. Due to this it will return single row only.. We're sure about this...